# Package Not Found

Tags: managed-package, package

We are having issues passing packages between dev and test.  The dev org is on NA7.  QA is using NA9

> **Package Not Found**
>   The requested package does not exist or has been deleted. Please contact the package publisher for assistance. If this is a recently uploaded package, please try again soon.

usually we are able to load and install the package 5 minutes after we receive the link from dev. salesforce needs to propogate the build to all their servers...

last time this occurred (when we received this msg and prevented me from installing) was when salesforce held all new builds from propagating because they were switching from spring '13 to summer '13 versions.

Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Yup, I uploaded a package about 4 hours ago and still waiting.

Comment: getting same error for one of the appxchange product.

Comment: ditto, gettings a package not available error when trying to install an appexchange product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance of the package uploader is **very** sporadic. I've had times ranging from < 5 mins - > 4hrs. No rhyme or reason.

Comment: I've seen times even longer than four hours (I believe the longest value so far was in the neighborhood of eight hours).